# stream standard output with PyZMQ

Tags: python, pyzmq

I have a client-side application which sends a message to a remote server, the message gets processed from the server and the result is sent back to the client.

A simplified example looks like:

**`client.py`**

```
import zmq
def get_message(msg, ip, port, socket, send_socket_type='pyobj'):
    socket.connect("tcp://%s:%s" % (ip, port))
    socket.send_string(msg)
    if send_socket_type=='pyobj':
        msg = socket.recv_pyobj()
    if send_socket_type=='string':
        msg = socket.recv_string()
    if send_socket_type=='json':
        msg = socket.recv_json()
    return msg
    socket.close()
```

**`server.py`**

```
import zmq
import time

port=9999
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
socket.bind("tcp://*:%s" % port)


def processmessage(msg):
    for i in range(10):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(1)
    return msg

while True:
    msg = socket.recv()
    print('message received from client:', msg)
    cmd = processmessage(msg)
    socket.send_pyobj(cmd)
    print('sending to client: %s ' % msg)
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

**Testing:**

```
server_env={'IP': ip, 'PORT': port}

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)

messages = ['first message', 'second message', 'third message']

for i in messages:
  msg = get_message('message', ip=server_env['IP'], port=server_env['PORT'], socket)
  print(msg)
```

My Question:

- How can I extend this simple client-server example to allow the client to receive the standard output generated by the process `processmessage()` running server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a context manager to redirect sys.stdout to a StringIO object while processing the message:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import io
import sys

@contextmanager
def capture():
    save_stdout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = io.StringIO()
    try:
        yield sys.stdout
    finally:
        sys.stdout = save_stdout


def processmessage(msg):
    with capture() as stdout:
        for i in range(10):
            print(i)
            time.sleep(1)
    return {
        'reply': msg,
        'stdout': stdout.getvalue(),
    }
```

Using this context manager lets you capture stdout during any block of code, and retrieve whatever output occurred on stdout via `stdout.getvalue()` after the end of the context. You can then send the reply with two fields: the result itself and the stdout captured during processing.

You can do the same with stderr if you are interested, either by:

1. redirecting stderr to the same StringIO object, so stdout/err are merged together, or
2. sending stderr to its own StringIO object if you want to keep them separate.

Comment: Thank you @minrk, this way I can recover and associate the `stdout` or any other info I need from the server by adding a `key: value` pair to what is returned by `processmessage()`. What I'm missing is the *streaming* part which is maybe not very clear in my question. For streaming, I mean the *server* keep the clients 'up-to-date' with the processes status, by sending/streaming the processes std-out while a process is still running.